# Angular route with canonical meta tag

Tags: angularjs

Im using angular routing but I need to add a canonical meta tag like you would for static pages. i.e.
`<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/page">`
But I would like to do it for each route.

Is that possible to do with Angular routing?

Comment: Yes, the site is built like an SPA. I guess I should ask is it possible to add a canonical link for each route?

Comment: You can use `$routeChangeSuccess` event and update meta tag href.

Comment: will search engines accept doing it that way?

Answer (score 1):

I think that is not actually now, but my resolution is:
in app.run() do this:

```
$rootScope.getCanonical = function() {
     return $location.$$protocol + '://' + $location.$$host + $location.$$path;
};
```

and in index.html add meta tag with rel="canonical"

```
<link rel="canonical" href="{{getCanonical()}}" />
```